# Angular 7 :Error with Angular routing **'router-outlet'** is not a known element:

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular7

I have tried to include all imports to the necessary files,But I have got the following  error while compiling. How could I solve it?

I have generated four differnet commonents Menu,home,contact,and about.Additional to this thare are also Header component that will later help to contain the memu bar to switch between the differnt components.And also footer component.The app-routing.ts and routes.ts files are also attached with this file,which helps for routing purpose.

**'router-outlet'** is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the

```
'@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<app-header></app-header>
    [ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@1:0
        at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
        at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5      /compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14830)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:24018)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:24005)
        at compiler.js:23948
        at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:23948)
        at compiler.js:23858
        at Object.then (compiler.js:1012)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23857)
```

**routes.ts** file

```js
 

 

      import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
        
        import { MenuComponent } from '../menu/menu.component';
        import { DishdetailComponent } from '../dishdetail/dishdetail.component';
        import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
        import { AboutComponent } from '../about/about.component';
        import { ContactComponent } from '../contact/contact.component';
        
        export const routes: Routes = [
          { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
          { path: 'menu',     component: MenuComponent },
          { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
                      ];
```

**app-routing.module.ts** file

```
   

 
            import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
            import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
            import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
            
            import { routes } from './routes';
            
            @NgModule({
              imports: [
                CommonModule,
                RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
              ],
              exports: [ RouterModule ],
              declarations: []
            })
            export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts** file

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
    import  {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
    import  {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
    import  {MatCardModule} from "@angular/material/card";
    import  {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/Button";
    import { FlexLayoutModule }  from '@angular/flex-layout';

    import 'hammerjs';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
    import { FooterComponent} from './footer/footer.component';
    import { HeaderComponent} from './header/header.component';
    import { DishdetailComponent } from './dishdetail/dishdetail.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from  './home/home.component'
    import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
    import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

    import {DishService} from './services/dish.service';

    import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
         @NgModule({
                  declarations: [
                  AppComponent,
                  MenuComponent,
                  DishdetailComponent,
                  HeaderComponent,
                  FooterComponent,
                  HomeComponent,
                  AboutComponent,
                  ContactComponent
                 ],
     imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatListModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        RouterModule
      ],` 
      `providers: [
        DishService
      ],`
     `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` 
   `})` 

    export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html** file

```html
   

<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are missing app-routing.module.ts inside the imports of AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    routingModule
  ],

})
export class AppModule{ }
```

Comment: add RoutingModule directly in AppModule

Comment: Also you can search about using shared module

Comment: What do you mean?Becasue I have already added AppRoutingModule to it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your `app.module.ts` file you have back ticks ``` in inappropriate places somewhere around `providers` & `bootstrap` array. I copied & pasted this from your own code so you can see it better:

```
      ...MatListModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        RouterModule
      ],` 
      `providers: [
        DishService
      ],`
     `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` 
   `})` 

    export class AppModule { }
```

---

**Do this:**
Remove all the back ticks in the app.module.ts file like I have done below and restart your terminal. This should solve any problems you are having.

```
      ...MatListModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        RouterModule
      ],
      providers: [
        DishService
      ],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })

    export class AppModule { }
```

---

I copied and pasted your code and worked on the files you provided information about. With the back ticks removed, your code works fine here on my laptop. Here's the result in the gif below, route works properly & no errors in the console. Example with just home & menu components.

**Final result:**

[image: Gif showing route works]

I removed all other things that didn't relate to routing from your code so that it would be easier to detect errors. Here's my folder structure.

**Folder structure:**

[image]

And here are the contents of my files:

**route.ts file:**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './menu/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'menu',     component: MenuComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

**app.module.ts file:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './menu/home.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts file:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**menu.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: '<h1>Menu Component</h1>'
})
export class MenuComponent {

}
```

**home.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: '<h1>Home Component</h1>'
})
export class HomeComponent {

}
```

Like I said, once I removed those unnecessary back ticks from the app.module.ts, your code worked fined with no errors.

Comment: which angular version are you working on? I am working on angular 11 and facing the same issue. Please help if you get a solution

Comment: I am working on Angular 7.And still couldn't able to solve the issue.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Petros, please check it again. Dhritiman, can you share the link to your question here in the comments?

Comment: Normally back ticks are typo errors,they doesn't exist in my code.But,If the code just worked for you,I will create the new app and check it.Than you!

Comment: Where is your 'app.component.html' file?

Comment: Oh. I see. Ok... I didn't create a app.component.html file. I just used a direct template in the app.component.ts file since the code there isn't much. Same for the home & menu components too. You can choose to create a separate html file if you prefer it.

Comment: Yeah, maybe making a new app to test just for routing like I have done above will help. It can be really frustrating to get stuck on one thing for days or weeks. I hope you get to the root of the problem soon. Just know whenever you find what the issue is, you get stronger and better at tracking bugs/issues.

Comment: Thank you!You have  helped me to figure the issue.I was stuck for a weeks,but starting everything from scratch helped me fix the issue.

Comment: Yay! Glad to know it's now solved. If you haven't deleted the old project, you can find time to try compare the old & the new. Probably you may find what caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have started everything from scratch.Then my issue was fixed.I don't exactly know where is my problem.But,probably I have made  routes file in separate folder.Making routes file in app-routing folder, fixed my issue.